# what is the value of $f'(1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

what is the value of $f'(1)$ ?

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(1+ 1/n)^m -1}{ 1+ 1/n -1}$

i know   that $f'(1)=\frac{(1+ 1/n)^m -1}{ 1+ 1/n -1}=\frac{(1+ 1/n)^m -1}{  1/n }$

but  here im confused  how can i find the value of $f'(1)$ ?

Comment: What is $f$ here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  see  umberto answer

Comment: So is this the answer for which you looking for?

Comment: ya,,,,exactly @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like $f(x) = x^m$ and you are evaluating the limit $$f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1}.$$
Since $f'(x) = mx^{m-1}$ (which is hopefully known) you get $f'(1) = m$.

Comment: thanks u @Umberto